# Click on Material Sortable Header with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, angular, selenium

I am trying to perform some automated tests using selenium on an Angular app. One test involves clicking a mat-sort-header. I have not been able to find a way to click the header using selenium.

The table will sort correctly when I click it, but I am unable to sort the table using Selenium.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Header">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="Header">Header</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.title}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"</tr>
</table>
```

My initial approach, which didn't work.

```py
sort_header = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[contains(@aria-label, 'Change Sorting for Header')]")
sort_header.click()
```

My second approach, which also didn't work.

```py
js = "document.querySelector('[aria-label="Change Sorting for Header"]').click();"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

The first approach gives a 'Message: element not interactable' error. I am able to console log the correct button in the second approach (which prints a button element to the console) by modifying the JS code. However, the element does not sort when the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: try this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ng-container[@matColumnDef="Header"]').click
 `
OR
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@mat-table]').click
`

Comment: @pop : have you tried my solution

Comment: @farhanpirzada The idea is that I'm able to sort the column by clicking. I can only use what is rendered as html for Selenium, so I can't use ng-container. I'm trying to click a specific column, so clicking on the table doesn't help me sort the column. Thank you, though.